# Getting UVC germicide lamps to work

Tags: compact-fluorescent-lamp

I recently bought four UVC lamps from Aliexpress  Shopping Website. The UVC look exactly like the one at the link below:

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005002703528485.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.main.17.230b733dBWS840&algo_pvid=52506a2f-5afb-483e-a54e-20087116bdc1&algo_exp_id=52506a2f-5afb-483e-a54e-20087116bdc1-8&pdp_npi=3%40dis%21THB%21188.44%21113.07%21%21%215.45%21%21%4021021d8f16893556533116845d077a%2112000021782405648%21sea%21TH%210&curPageLogUid=QDwsLQZEwavZ

If the above link is not working I have inserted picture of the UVC lamp.
[image]

I have been trying for very many days [on and off] trying to get the lamp to light up.

1. On one occasion, I connect AC220 volts to the two terminals of the lamp - the lamp blew up. The filaments were burnt out, I presumed, because they were blacken.
2. I tried to connect two types of electronic ballast I purchased online and connect to the two terminals of the lamp. The lamp failed to light up.

I am wondering what type of UVC lamp I had purchased? Can any expert please guide me on how I can get these lamps to light up.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you realize that looking at ultraviolet light can blind you? There have been a number of cases of people damaging their eyes with UVC lights in the past few years since people started trying to use them to kill COVID. If you don't know what you're doing with these you should not learn by experimenting, you only get two eyes.

Comment: UVC lamps have negative differential resistance which require a ballast that matches the lamp.

Comment: @qrk That's an answer, please use the answer box below to post it. Answering in comments is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be electrically similar to a common **9W two-pin** lamp as used in (say) desk lamps.

I had trouble accessing the Ali page ('not available in your area') so copied from VPN access:
[image]

It *will* require a ballast. For example, [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_doeRLhFg1rgUeUk44AnrZ3skCIkYIOJ/view) is one suited for 120VAC/60Hz mains that does not require a starter (I think a starter is built into the bulbs in this style, but I could be wrong on that point - the 13W types definitely make the old-timey pinging and flickering as they start for the white light similar lamps).

Your mains voltage, frequency and safety approval agencies are apparently different, so you should search for an appropriate product for your region.

Comment: Thanks for this Spehro. You remind me of the fact that CFL do require a ballast to work.  I will try to add a ballast to my circuit and see if it will light up.

Comment: For anyone trying to get the UVC lamp just like mine to work, kindly add a ballast and you will sleep well. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of inexpensive and quality commodity fluorescent ballasts out there for illumination tier fluorescents.  The kind made to make visible light.

UV lamps, while they use the same socket form factors as visible fluorescents, **are not ballast-compatible** with lighting fluorescents, and require special ballasts tuned for them.  Unfortunately this is common in fluorescent design - T8 and T12 lighting tubes are pin compatible but not ballast compatible.

Trust me, we got a huge stream of these requests in March 2020, and **there was no good answer** except do the legwork to find the specialty ballast designed for these UV lamps.  No new answers have emerged since.

I might imagine a UV light maker might design a bulb to work with lighting ballasts, but they would be shouting that very loudly as a feature, if they did.

Consult the factory for the recommended ballast for the lamps you purchased.  In the future, do this research and identify a compatible lamp/ballast pair that are designed to work with each other, before buying a thing.

If the factory provides shoddy support, then choose suppliers more carefully in the future.

> On one occasion, I connect AC220 volts to the two terminals of the lamp - the lamp blew up.

Fire the person who is giving you advice on how to work with fluorescents. This was dangerous and it could have literally exploded in your face.

Unfortunately this destroyed the bulb, and it is now garbage.  Nothing will light it up now.  It contains mercury, so dispose of it legally.